# Is there any useful source on High Bias vs High variance issue on Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks

I've been struggling to analyize my NN model. I've studied through andrew ng's course, but there are some results that cannot be explained by the course. Is there any useful source on  High Bias vs High variance issue on NN?

Comment: Hi. Your question in the body of the post seems to be slightly different than the question on the title. Can you please ask just one question?

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/bias-and-variance-in-machine-learning-51fdd38d1f86). might be helpful.